# Can't use datetime.strptime() in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a list in which each element is itself a two element list containing some dates:

```
d = [['2004:08:16:09:54:58', 'peach'],
['2013:05:10:19:57:50', 'eggplant'],
['2007:05:24:07:37:51', 'zucchini,']]
```

For each list nested in the list 'd', I want to use datetime.strptime() to convert each 'string' date to a datetime type, while keeping the second element unchanged, i.e. ['2004:08:16:09:54:58', 'peach'] --> [2004-08-16 09:54:58, 'peach']

Doing the following works:

```
print(datetime.strptime('2004:08:16:09:54:58', '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S'))
>>2004-08-16 09:54:58
```

But it doesn't seem to work in a loop:

```
for i in d:
    datetime.strptime(i[0], '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S')
print d[0]:
>>['2004:08:16:09:54:58', 'peach']
```

If I try to make a new list with the converted strings instead of changing the original list, I encounter a different problem:

```
new_list = []
for i in d:
    new_list.append(datetime.strptime(i[0],'%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S'))
    new_list.append(i[1])
print(new_list[0])

>> 2004-08-16 09:54:58
```

Here, suddenly the table only has the correctly converted datetime object but not the fruit/vegetable object.

Can anyone provide insight into both cases? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Quick and easy fix, you forgot to override the previous value. Here is how you should have done it.

```
for i in d:
    i[0] = datetime.strptime(i[0], '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S')
print d[0]
```

Comment: In python 3, this results in the following:

    [datetime.datetime(2004, 8, 16, 9, 54, 58), 'peach'], instead of (2004-08-16 09:54:58) 

Anyone know of a quick fix for python 3?  Thanks for your input

Comment: You simply have to format it again after here is an example:

```d = list(map(lambda x: (datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), x[1]), d))```

Answer (score 0):

As you're appending first the time and only then the fruit name the name itself will be in `new_list[1]`.

if you want the new list to be a list of lists (i.e. - exactly like the old list) you should use:

```
for i in d:
    new_list.append([datetime.strptime(i[0],'%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S'), i[1]])
```

Thus appending both values as a list into your `new_list`.

If you wish to save the `datetime` with the format (i.e. - 2004-08-16 09:54:58) you can do it while saving it as a string, either by using `.isoformat()`:

```
datetime.strptime(i[0],'%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S').isoformat(' ')
```

Documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

or by using string formatting:

```
'{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.strptime(i[0],'%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S'))
```

if you wish to know more about formatting you can check out:
https://pyformat.info/#datetime

Comment: In python 3, this results in the following: [datetime.datetime(2004, 8, 16, 9, 54, 58), 'peach'], instead of (2004-08-16 09:54:58) Anyone know of a quick fix for python 3? Thanks for your input

Comment: @AFKRD You can use `isoformat()` -`datetime.strptime(i[0],'%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S').isoformat()`. but it will save it as a string. https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat


You can also use string formatting - `'{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.strptime(i[0],'%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S'))`